# Подскажите как написать регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярные выражения, под такие описания

1. Одна латинская буква, за которой следуют 7 цифр или две латинские буквы за которыми следуют семь цифр.
2. 10 цифр, затем символ "/", затем 1 цифра

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{7}$`

Comment: Второй напишите сами

Answer (score 0):

1.Если нужно, чтобы вся строка удовлетворяла регулярному выражению, то подойдёт ответ eccs01103

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{7}$/
```

Если нужно найти все совпадения

```
/[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{7}/g
```

2.Вся строка должна удовлетворять выражению

```
/^\d{10}//\d{1}$/
```

Если нужно найти все совпадения

```
/\d{10}//\d{1}/g
```